# Div Toggle Show/Hide spilling over Parent Div

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle

I have a form that generates a sortable div. I have added a div inside that div that displays on click. The problem is that this div spills over onto the divs below.

I can solve this by putting that div outside of the "click" div but then the sortable functionality does not work.

I have tried all sorts of styles to solve this but no luck. Please help if you can. Cheers

The fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/rRYTa/1/

Comment: Thanks guys I tried those solutions but they arent working the way I need it to. I found a work around by removing the height style of .div_menu_button. Its not exactly what I want so I am still open to any suggestions. See updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/rRYTa/3/

Comment: I tried both of your fiddles in Safari and they both appear to operate the same... I'm not seeing anything spill over in either one.  Can you better explain how to replicate the problem you're seeing?  Or better yet, post a screenshot.  Also, please explain what is still deficient about your solution in the second fiddle... what part about it is still _"not exactly what I want"_?

Comment: Hi, sorry @Sparky672 I went with the workaround I found. My boss is happy with it so, so am I. I answered the question this morning. Cheers

Comment: Thank-you Clint.  I understand you fixed your problem but Stack Overflow is also about helping future readers as much as it is about helping the OP.  This question will be more helpful to them if they can actually see/understand exactly what it was that went wrong and how it was fixed.  Any details or clarifications you can add to your question and/or answer would be appreciated by all.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll update the question with more info when I get a break. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.div_menu_button had a height style attributed to it and that was preventing the button from expanding on the toggle. Once I made the height: auto; it worked fine. Stupid mistake I should have seen it before posting this question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/rRYTa/2/

I simply set `div.div_menu_button` to have `position:relative`, and did `.menu_button_info {position:absolute; top:0; left:0}`.

The only issue I see with this is that it appears on top of the Menu Item name. However, if you stuck that name into its own element, you could easily calculate the width of that element and adjust the `left` css property on the corresponding `.menu_button_info`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the toggled div to show up "inside" it's parent, you can position the "div_menu_button" as relative and it's children as "absolute:

```
div.div_menu_button{
    ...
    position:relative;
}

.menu_button_info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fparent/2HezH/